# What does "invested" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://youtu.be/jU7I5UpTMrM?t=2m20s

Here, Gilbert says "invested", staring at Anne. I searched the dictionary but it says "invested" means "Officially endowed with authority or power", which doesn't make any sense to me.

What exactly does "invested" mean here?

Comment: it's a figurative extension from [sense 14 here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/invested) *to invest money; make an investment*, where the "invested resources" involve time / energy / personal commitment, rather than actual money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Invested** there is used in the figurative sense "emotionally committed" or "putting all one has into an effort".   He is referring to her very emotional (some would say overly emotional) acting.

Comment: So "invested" here has a positive connotation, right? But how did you know that it was used in a figurative sense? I mean, we know a word is used figuratively because there's a similarity(?) between the words. But from the definition of "invested" I found ("officially endowed with authority or power"), I could never think of this meaning.

Comment: *Invested* can mean "endowed with authority" but it more usually means "committing resources with expectation of a future payback."  Typically it is used in a financial sense but can also be figuratively stretched to mean emotions, etc.

Comment: @dbwlsld: We know from context that he is not talking about investment of money or other resources in the hope of a literal "payback" in the form of some kind of goods or money. So, if we are already aware of all of the possible meanings of **invested**, including the figurative one, we can use context to decide which meaning is appropriate. If we are not already aware of all of these meanings, we must consult one more more GOOD dictionaries, to get a sense of the possible meanings, and then use context to decide which is appropriate.